# 'Default Value' set to True/False in Metadata Schema not being selected and displayed in Component/Keywords

Tags: web8.5, schema, keyword

We are creating a Metadata schema for our country list that is a Category-Keyword in SDL Web 8.5.

In Metadata schema we are defining, whether the country in from EMEA region or not by setting a flag in Metadata for each Keyword to T/F.
However, even though we select default value in Metadata schema to 'False', in the Keywords no value is selected.
[image]

Please, could you help me understand what have I missed?

TIA

Comment: What is the field data type, Is it drop-down or checkbox or radio button?

Comment: I have kept it as a Drop-down.

Comment: I did a test quick test it's working fine, I did create a keyword and selected metadata schema by default that value shows False and saved and accessed using core service to validated it's stored and accessible.
 How and where you are trying to validate and saying that keyword meta value is getting empty?

Comment: added image to question

Comment: Update your question with metadata schema screen shot?. I will anwser to show my test screens for your reference,

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate your keyword metadata using core service to check whether it's stored in CMS or not.

```
ReadOptions read = new ReadOptions();
KeywordData keyword = (KeywordData)core.Read("tcm:4-409-1024", read);
Console.WriteLine(keyword.Metadata);
```

Output:

```
<Metadata xmlns="uuid:64e50b91-ec9e-4bd4-9c66-84a26319efa2">
<IsEMEARegion>False</IsEMEARegion>
</Metadata>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You field is mandatory Velu - their's is not.